# Extract ammonium sulfate from water

Tags: water, solutions, extraction

What is the best method to extract ammoniumsulfate from water?

The assignment is as follows:

> Manure is being processed and the product left is a mixture between water and ammonium sulfate, transporting the mixture costs a lot of money. So we only want the ammonium sulfate.

What is the best method to do this on a big scale? Evaporation isn't a good option since it costs too much energy to heat the big amounts of water.

Comment: Depends on if you want the sulfate or ammonium or both.

Comment: You would probably have to add a lot of grain alcohol to precipitate the ammonium sulfate out (ammonium sulfate is insoluble in ethanol), and recovering the alcohol for re-use wouldn't be free either.  Does this route look too costly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Evaporation isn't a good option since it costs too much energy to heat the big amounts of water.

Is it? I've seen prices around USD 130-150 per ton (minimum order of 25 tons) for ammonium sulfate with a purity around 99%. You might want to calculate the costs to operate a production plant using natural gas (or other fuels) for evaporation yourself.

There is however a **different energy source** that you might want to take into consideration: **the sun**.

Evaporation of water from solutions of sodium chloride in **open ponds** by **solar heating** alone has a long tradition in the production of sodium chloride in the form of [sea salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_salt).

---

**Update**

Ammonium sulfate will not evaporate from the open ponds. At temperatures between 235-280 °C, it will start to decompose.

However, if surface temperatures reach that level under irradiation with unconcentrated sunlight, the fate of the ammonium sulfate is the least of your worries ;)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I have a question, as soon as the evaporation in an open pond starts, won't the ammonium sulfate start to evaporate too?

Comment: @KarimLeurink I've updated my answer.